# MySQL- Select only one matching record

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has its primary key as the combination of 4 columns say `column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4`. There are some records in this table which has multiple values for the same combination of `<column_1, column_2>` values. I want to write a SQL query so as to select distinct column_1 and column_2 combinations with any one random column_3 and column_4 combination.

Example:
Table

```
column_1          column_2          column_3  column_4
column_1_value_1  column_2_value_1  2000      america
column_1_value_1  column_2_value_1  1000      europe
column_1_value_2  column_2_value_2  3000      asia
```

I want the output to be

```
column_1_value_1  column_2_value_1  2000      america
column_1_value_2  column_2_value_2  3000      asia
```

OR

```
column_1_value_1  column_2_value_1  1000      europe
column_1_value_2  column_2_value_2  3000      asia
```

I tried the query `select column_1, column_2, max(column_3), max(column_4) from table group by column_1, column_2` but this provides the output:

```
column_1_value_1  column_2_value_1  2000      europe
column_1_value_2  column_2_value_2  3000      asia
```

This output is incorrect because column_3 value `2000` does not match with column_4 value `europe`.

Can someone please help me formulate the query as per my requirement?

Comment: "  SELECT * FROM `table_name` GROUP By column_1, column_2 "  

why you used max for column_3 and column_4 is there and specific requirement. 
I just fire the above query and its output as you want.

Comment: max is as good as getting random value from the column so I used max.

Comment: @bhargavkatakpara You are selecting all columns but grouping by only selected columns. This is conceptually incorrect in my opinion

Comment: Okay, @sagar got your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER` here for a MySQL 8+ option:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column_1, column_2 ORDER BY RAND()) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

A solution involving joins, and avoiding analytic functions, might look like:

```
SELECT t1.column_1, t1.column_2, t1.column_3, t1.column_4
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT column_1, column_2, MAX(column_3) AS max_column_3
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY column_1, column_2
) t2
    ON t1.column_1 = t2.column_1 AND
       t1.column_2 = t2.column_2 AND
       t1.column_3 = t2.max_column_3;
```

This second approach arbitrarily chooses the `(column_1, column_2)` single record as the one which has the highest value for `column_3`.

Comment: Thanks for reply Tim. Could you please provide me a solution with simple SQL syntax? I am okay if it involves joins of the table with itself

Comment: Check the updated answer, which is along the lines of what you were trying to do originally.

Comment: I just realized that this may not work if there are multiple records with same value for Column_1, Columns_2, Column_3. Posted little modification to your solution as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Little modification to the answer posted by Tim.

```
SELECT t1.column_1, t1.column_2, t1.column_3, max(t1.column_4)
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT column_1, column_2, MAX(column_3) AS max_column_3
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY column_1, column_2
) t2
    ON t1.column_1 = t2.column_1 AND
       t1.column_2 = t2.column_2 AND
       t1.column_3 = t2.max_column_3
    GROUP BY t1.column_1, t1.column_2, t1.column_3;
```

Comment: Please consider _deleting_ this answer as it does not agree with the question actually asked.